# is python PIP important for machine learning or python programming

Tags: python-3.x

I need to know that does python3 has already installed PIP or it needs to be installed and is it important for machine learning ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Pip is just an package installer for python, so you are probably gonna want to use it in order to get some machine learning related packages. It comes as an .py script with python3 installation. You don't need to install anything special in order to use pip.

[Pip description page](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)